# Radial similarity of Newton polytopes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, convex-polytopes, jacobian-conjecture

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and assume that $p,q \in k[x,y]$ is a Jacobian pair, namely, $p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in k^*$
(= the determinant of the Jacobi matrix $\in k^*$).

It is known that the Newton polygons of $p$ and $q$ are radially similar, 
see, for example, [Theorem 1.2](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Vkf8CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=Automorphisms%20of%20affine%20spaces,%20A.%20van%20den%20Essen&source=bl&ots=iztNS-iHNp&sig=S-23aqf1_M-ai5EjR3N8tCeOAxY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyhqjH5_nZAhWIEVAKHVhKAroQ6AEISTAH#v=onepage&q=radial&f=false).

Now assume that $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a 'Jacobian $n$-tuple' (= the determinant of their Jacobi matrix $\in k^*$), $n \geq 3$.

> Is there some kind of a radial similarity result for the $n$ Newton polytopes of 
>   $f_1,\ldots,f_n$?
>
> For example: Is it true that if the Newton polytope of some $f_i$
>   has a vertex on the $x$-axis, then there exists $j \neq i$ such that the Newton
>   polytope of $f_j$ also has a vertex on the $x$-axis?

**Remarks:** (1) [O. Hadas](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242982861_On_the_vertices_of_Newton_polytopes_associated_with_an_automorphism_of_the_ring_of_polynomials) has dealt with Newton polytopes of automorphisms of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (here our given endomorphism $x_i \mapsto f_i$ is not known to be an automorphism, of course); perhaps definition 5.1 of Newton-tame automorphism can be adjusted to our case here.
(2) Perhaps [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6d80/fcdc480dcd6554950de1679fe603036c8c54.pdf) is relevant.